# Unable to follow AWS documentation to dynamically query a collection

Tags: collections, aws-amplify, figma-api

I'm trying to follow the AWS [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/console/uibuilder/collections/) for UI development with Figma. Unfortunately I reach a point where the instructions no longer tally with what I'm seeing in my console. The image where the docs show "Link Collection To Data Model", on the right side of the screen, doesn't appear on my own, which shows this instead:

[image]

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong? Can't fathom it so far.

Comment: Tap where it says "Local setup intructions", it'll give you some examples.

Comment: Thanks Arturo. I've had a look through that and it shows how to manually perform CRUD operations via DataStore, but the instructions that I linked to seem to suggest a lot of those kind of operations can be created and managed directly in the UI Library section of the Amplify Console.